# C# best way to delete a many collection in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have the following classes with one to many relation

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
    public Category Category {get;set;}
}

My datacontext is as shown below:

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to replace the existing products collectino for a category with a new collection of category.
What is the best way to do this in EF?

Basically, from the collection provided, if productid is specified, then do an update, if entity is not available, then add new product. 
if not in the list delete from the database.

Here is what i am trying to.

```
using (var dbCtx = new MyDBEntities())
{
    //1- Get data from database
    //2- Find newly added items
    //3- Find deleted items
    //4- Find modified
    //5- Mark all added items entity state to Added
    //6- Mark all deleted item entity state to Deleted
    //7- Apply modified items current property values to existing property values
    dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything ? any code for that?

Comment: I have updated with what i am trying to do. I am not asking for any sample code. but want to know the best way to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let's pay attention to these lines:

1. Get data from database
2. Find newly added items
3. Find deleted items
4. Find modified
5. Mark all added items entity state to Added
6. Mark all deleted item entity state to Deleted
7. Apply modified items current property values to existing property values

***Don't you think that you are trying to write very similar codes for defining the state of each entity?***
 We can handle all of these operations with a single command.

You can easily achieve this with the newly released [EntityGraphOperations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityGraphOperations/) for Entity Framework Code First. I am the author of this product. And I have published it in the [github](https://github.com/FarhadJabiyev/EntityGraphOperations), [code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1131322/Automatically-Define-the-State-of-All-Entities-in) and [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityGraphOperations/). With the help of `InsertOrUpdateGraph` method, it will automatically set your entities as `Added` or `Modified`. And with the help of `DeleteMissingEntities` method, you can delete those entities which exists in the database, but not in the current collection.

```
// This will set the state of the main entity and all of it's navigational 
// properties as `Added` or `Modified`.
context.InsertOrUpdateGraph(category)
       .After(entity =>
       {
            // And this will delete missing products.
            entity.HasCollection(p => p.Products)
               .DeleteMissingEntities();
       });
```

---

***Update:*** 
After some comments, I have decided to make sample project and explain how to write a sample project. I have updated [my article in Code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1131322/Automatically-Define-the-State-of-All-Entities-in) with a step-by-step demonstration and a sample project is ready for downloading.

Comment: Is this working for you @Mukil Deepthi ? we would like to know about this interesting API. hope you'll give a feedback.

Comment: @Sampath I couldn't find a time to add sample project in Visual Studio. But, I will add sample project tomorrow and will update my answer. Hope, you will see the result. Thanks for interest.

Comment: yep,it's Great.please let us know once you'll do that :)

Comment: @Sampath I have updated my code-project article with the project and step-by-step demonstration. Check my updated answer for the link.

Comment: Sure.I'll go through the COP article and will give a feedback there too.+1 for your hardworking.Thanks :) .But I'm really disappointing about the feedback of the OP (@Mukil Deepthi).He's continuously ignoring his feedback.Which is very BAD.

Comment: @Sampath Thanks very much. May be he has other works or he was waiting for a demo project.